# How do I determine the monotonicity of $y=2^{\frac{1}{x-a}}$?

Tags: functions, derivatives, monotone-functions

I've worked out the derivative and the critical point:

$f'(x)=-\frac{2^{\frac{1}{x-a}}\ln 2}{(x-a)^2}$
and $x-a=0\iff x=a$,

but I don't know where to go from here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The map $x\mapsto2^x$ is strictly increasing and the map $x\mapsto\frac1{x-a}$ is strictly decreasing in both maximal intervals in which it is defined, $(-\infty,a)$ and $(a,\infty)$. Therefore, the same thing applies to your function: it is strictly decreasing in both maximal intervals in which it is defined, $(-\infty,a)$ and $(a,\infty)$.

Comment: Is there any way to prove that the second map is decreasing on both intervals using the first derivative?

Comment: Sure: if you differentiate it, you get $-\frac1{(x-a)^2}<0$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint. The composition of a monotone increasing function and a monotone decreasing function is decreasing.  (Also decreasing composed with decreasing is increasing.)

Thus, you could break up your composite expression into its constituent parts, and figure out where the parts increase and decrease.